# How to subscribe for push notifications for any user defined folder using EWS managed API

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I am subscribing to push notifications as below:

```
var subscription = myExchangeService.SubscribeToPushNotifications(
                                    new[] { new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox) },
                                    new Uri(somePostBackUrl),
                                    15,
                                    null,
                                    EventType.NewMail,
                                    EventType.Created,
                                    EventType.Deleted,
                                    EventType.Modified,
                                    EventType.Moved,
                                    EventType.Copied);
```

Now my requirement is to subscribe for notifications for any user defined folders as well. So 1) How can I get the list of all subfolders/userdefined folders. 2) how can I subscribe to a list of those folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) How can I get the list of all subfolders/userdefined folders.

You need to use FindFolders to list the subfolders of whatever parent Folder you want to look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folder.findfolders(v=exchg.80).aspx If you want to recuse to grandchildren of those folder set the traversal property of the FolderView class https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folderview.traversal(v=exchg.80).aspx to Deep.

> . 2) how can I subscribe to a list of those folders?

Once you have the FolderId from the above FindFolders call you then subscribe to each folder in turn. The other option is to subscribe to all folders in the Mailbox eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.subscribetopushnotificationsonallfolders(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Works fine. Thanks @GlenScales

Comment: One question though, can I set the PageSize to a maximum number to make sure it includes all folders?

Comment: If you using FindFolder you need to set it to 1000 and then page the results like you would items. Most mailboxes won't have more the 1000 items but the throttling policies will mean it will only return a max of 1000

Comment: Okay, thanks again. I will implement paging in the results.